# How to use layout components in functions which are out of activities and fragments in Android?

Tags: android, xml, function, android-studio, kotlin

I have a layout and I want to use its component in a function. How can I do that?

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#0055FF"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the function:

```
fun Context.Dialog(){
    title.setOnItemClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(this,"OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

But **title** is not recognized in the **Dialog** function. I don't want to use **Dialog** function in an activity or a fragment.

Comment: Why not declaring a function which contains this `onClick` and calling it from `Context.Dialog`?

Comment: How? Please post an answer

Comment: Your using extension function for this and It's the completely wrong approach for this kind of logic.

Comment: Just leaving out the code, in plain english, what is it that you trying to achieve?

Comment: See the correct answer please @ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't move initialization of `OnCLickListener` out of activity or fragment, because there (in activity or fragment) you have access to all views defined in the layout. But if you want to create a separate function out of activity or fragment you need to pass either views or activity or fragment as parameters:

```
// passing views
fun showDialog(title: View) {
    title.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(title.context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
}

// passing activity
fun showDialog(activity: Activity) {
    val title: View = activity.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(activity, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
}

// passing fragment
fun showDialog(fragment: Fragment) {
    val title: View? = fragment.view?.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title?.setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(fragment.context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
}
```

Also you can create an extension function on `View`:

```
fun View.showDialogWhenClick() {
    setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
}
```

And use it in Activity or Fragment like this:

```
title.showDialogWhenClick()
```

Comment: Please explain better that how can I use layout component in a function. When I use in my code I get this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get the reference to title first. Then set listeners and such.

in your activity

```
fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:Bundle){
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)
Context.Dialog(this);
}
```

in your Context.Dialog:

```
fun Context.Dialog(activity:Activity){
    var title = activity.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title?.setOnItemClickListener{
        Toast.makeText(this,"OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

or something like that

Comment: How should I change my function?

Comment: Where are you declaring the function? You need to get the reference to the title text view after you have inflated the layout. So in activity.onCreate() after setContentView() do TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title); then you can do with it whatever you want

Comment: As I said in the question, the function is out of activity and fragment

Comment: If its just a static function then you would have to pass it in the argument. Context.Dialog(title:TextView){ title.setOnItemChangeListener({}); }

Comment: What if I have several components in the layout?